# how to use table name as variable in insert query statement in python with sqlite3 as database ( don't use concatenation of strings

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
cur.execute(
    "INSERT INTO  tool1 ( USERID , USER_NAME , GROUP_NAME) VALUES (108535, ? , ? )",
     ( userName, groupName ) );
```

tool1 needs to be variable

Comment: Why do you not want to use string concatenation?

Comment: `cur.execute("INSERT INTO  %s (USERID , USER_NAME , GROUP_NAME) VALUES (108535, ? , ?)" % table_name, (userName, groupName))` or `cur.execute("INSERT INTO  {} (USERID , USER_NAME , GROUP_NAME) VALUES (108535, ? , ?)".format(table_name), (userName, groupName))` ?